# What's the reason behind browsers re-downloading Internet media content?

Tags: browser, temporary-files, file-download

You already have most text, pdf html, image, audio and video files obviously downloaded when you are currently reading/listening/watching them on your browser. However, when you want that file to be stored in your Documents folder for later use, instead of moving/copying that file from temporal folder, browser just downloads file again. Is there even something to make browser behave as I'd like to?

Comment: What browsers did you test this with?

Comment: I agree with Ben N. You should probably specify which browser (including version) and OS (including version) you saw this with, and at least one example of a specific sequence of actions that illustrates the problem. In some cases, the file might not be completely downloaded when you're viewing it. It may have only downloaded the parts you viewed, and it may have already purged parts you're no longer looking at (especially with long HD videos).

Answer (score 1):

This is not true at all. When you open an image and right click/save it to your local folder, the browser does not download the file again, it just moves it from the cache or virtual memory to the specified location on your hard drive.